# How to copy entire directory structure?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am copying 10,000 files from one directory to another directory.

Both directory structures have the same files; however, the sizes might be different.

How do I force overwriting on files that have different sizes and DO NOT copy files that are the same size?

So far I have this:

```
$source = 'D:\Test1'
$destination = 'D:\test2'
$exclude = @('*.db','test2.log')
$sourcelist = Get-ChildItem $source -exclude $exclude
foreach ($file in $sourcelist){
  $result = test-path -path "$destination\*" -include $file
  if ($result -like "False"){
    #uncomment the next line to see the value being passed to the $file parameter
    #Write-Host $file
    Copy-Item "$file" -Destination "$destination"
  }
}
```

I think that will copy files that do not exist on the destination. However, I also want to copy files that DO exist but where their size differs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) instead of trying to re-invent it in PowerShell.

```
robocopy D:\Test1 D:\Test2 /s
```

If you also want to include files where only attributes differ ("tweaked files"), add `/it` as well.

Comment: The `/mir` option to only copy new or different files, and delete from destination where removed from source is a very efficient way to update the destination.

Comment: @Richard so would the full thing be robocopy D:\Test1 D:\Test2 /s /mir /it ??

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Tweaked files are files that have the same size and timestamp, but different attributes (e.g. source file was changed to `hidden`). See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/314511) on SU for an explanation of robocopy's terminology.

Answer (score -1):

I think check $sourcelist files LastWrite Time Stamps and then compare it to the destination files time stamps.