# Copy nested folder structures

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am copying over all items from one directory to another that has files and subfolders with files using this command I am using is simple:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $source).ForEach({$_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest})
```

It works but the problem is that it doesn't copy files within subfolders to the destination subfolders they belong but to the main destination folder instead. Wondering if I can I modify this command in a concise way so it's still a one-liner and does that?
The difference between this and similar questions is that I have nested folder structure with sub-folders and files within them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy entire directory structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562443/how-to-copy-entire-directory-structure)

Comment: Did you bother taking an actual look at the answers to that question?